# django admin edit model select/prefetch_related?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django website, with model `Event`, lets say:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='%(class)s_home')
    away = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='%(class)s_away')
    ...

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("team's name", max_length=100)
```

Using ForeignKeys for this was a bad idea, but anyway, how to make this usable in Django Admin page?
In admin edit event page, a ton of foreign keys is fetched for this:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/event/event/116255/`

It produces tons of selects like:
`SELECT "event_team"."id", "event_team"."name" FROM "event_team" WHERE "event_team"."id" = 346;`

and page dies. I was playing with these:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'home', 'away', 'date_game', 'sport', 'result')
    search_fields = ['home__name', 'away__name']
    list_select_related = (
        'home', 'away', 'league', 'sport', ...
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related(*self.list_select_related)
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

But no luck.

Comment: I think you don't need to call ``select_related`` in ``get_queryset``. Django should automatically call it if you specified ``list_select_related``.

Comment: but it does not work for update page :(

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: Django==1.8.17, but will probably upgrade soon

Comment: What do you mean page dies?

Comment: its calling thousands `SELECT "event_team"."id" ...` until timeout is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was my mistake and I did not even mention it in question :(

So this is my model, but I did not mention important part if it:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='%(class)s_home')
    away = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='%(class)s_away')
    merged = models.ForeignKey('Event', null='True', blank='True')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + self.home.name + " - " + self.away.name
```

Problem was not with `home` or `away`, but with `merged` field, that fetched `self.home.name` and `self.away.name` for each event.

Replaced with

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Event id: {}'.format(self.id)
```

and added `merged` to `list_select_related`
fixed my problem. Thanks for help and sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 2):

### The simplest, quickest way

It would be to add `raw_id_fields` on your ModelAdmin ([Django ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)) :

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("home", "away")
```

It would result in a inputText with the FK field ids in such as :
[image: Django ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields text Input example].
Loading will be fast as it won't populate a select list with ALL the teams.
You'll have the Django admin change_view of the `Team ModelAdmin` to select the teams, thanks to the browse icon.

### A nicer way ?

A lot more elegant on the UX side of things, it requires you to know part of the name of the team: using an ajax autocomplete widget to represent your field.

You could use for example [Django Autocomplete Light (DAL) quick tutorial](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) by having a custom form for your admin and a `autocompleteModelSelect2` for your `home` and `away` fields (with 2 differents QS in the ajax view).
It will produce a field looking like:

[image: DAL autocomplete ModelSelect2 widget example].
The tutorial of this link have all you need!

Or you can chose another third party plugin or build your own field/widget to produce a similar result.

Comment: I can not believe, I can not stay with current UI and just fetch all foreign keys in few SQL requests :(

Comment: In your current UI, you have two selects, with N team-options each. If you have 10 000 teams; It will be 20 000 options in the html rendered page. The first solution I propose, will let you achieve what you want in 2 extra steps for the user.

Comment: OK, this explains why the sql is arround the Event and not the Team! well :)

Answer (score 2):

I think @ppython's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46812669/3979725) is the simplest and works perfectly but I ended up using `autocomplete_fields` instead of `raw_id_fields`. Achieving a more friendly approach, it has been available since Django 2.0.

Following the answer, it'll be something like this:

```py
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['home', 'away']
```